# How do you I get my Visual Studio 2019 fix

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1

Last week I had an issues while working on a project asp.net core mvc 3.1 in which I was unable to create Controller. I had to update my visual studio before it was fixed. Now I am using the last version of VS19 and I tried to add a view from a controller class that was initailly created by me and I keep getting the below error message. please I need a quick help as this is really delaying me from completing the recent project I am working on. thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rhBi.png)

Comment: possibly related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436290/there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-the-value-1-outside-t

Comment: Open Solution explorer and look under references.  You can right click the nuget libary so see location of dll (right click reference or open csproj with Notepad).  You may need to rebuild the nuget.    The target version of the Nuget may not be compatible with VS19 and need to be rebuilt. Visual Studio expects either the dll to be in the same bin folder of executable, or the full path name where the reference is located.  I suspect that the new version of VS create an new folder in the project bin folder and the nuget dll is not in the correct bin folder.

Comment: Thanks guyz I have actually gotten it fixed yesterday after alot of troubleshooting and helps from senior colleagues all I just do is to clear my ComponentModelCache wich resides inside my AppData